# How can I save a editext and a image on a single file?

Tags: android, file-io

How can i create and edit a file which can contain both text and image.

I was able to save a file and edit it again which has text only. I did this by getting a text from a multiline edittext. i have added a imageview and set an image to it. But i do not know how to save it and retrieve for editing.

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_edit);

txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtData);
img =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

final String path = "/sdcard/ram/notebook/lesson";

try {
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";
        String aBuffer = "";
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
        }
        txtData.setText(aBuffer);
        myReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

btnWriteSDFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWriteSDFile);
btnWriteSDFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    String notes = txtData.getText().toString()+ img.getBackground();
    try {
          FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(notes);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done writing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      }// onClick
}); // btnWriteSDFile
}
```

I have tried using canvas. but it saves the text and image as a jpg, which is not editable (correct me if i am wrong).

Please help me how can i do this..

Comment: your should capture mobile screen...for achieve it.

Comment: save an image in a text file doesn't make much sense. use 2 files

Comment: `img.getBackground();` is not a String representation of the background image.

Comment: @DynamicMind: Thank u 4 replying..Plz help on how this can be done and can this be editted

Comment: While I was working on an image editing project in the university a while ago written in Java I was achieving this as saving the file as some custom extension and it was working. Not sure if it will work on Android, but you can give a try. For example save the file as .and or something else and try to open it via your app.

Comment: @Android-Developer: how can i append the image to the text, in a custom extension.

Comment: how are you drawing the image and the text? Using canvas / surfaceview or something else?

Comment: I select the image from gallery or take it from the camera to set it in the imageview and get the text from multiline edittext

Comment: I guess you should use canvas to draw the image and the text and save it with custom extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this by the below code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sv = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    sv.addView(ll);
    setContentView(sv);
Button b1 = new (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
saveAsJpg();
            }
        });

}
public void saveAsJpg ()
{
    //Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(sv.getWidth(), sv.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    sv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = sv.getDrawingCache();
      try {
          b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/ram/ert/d.jpg"));
          Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
        }

}
```